# Matlab size of image (x,y)

Tags: image, matlab

why when I used size function in Matlab for my image the result was ans = 600   800   but my real image size = (800, 600)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of difference in conventions. When we say an image is 800x600 we generally mean it 800 columns by 600 rows.  However when Matlab reports the size of a matrix it does it using standard matrix indexing which is row then column. So size(A) = (800, 600) means that the image is 800 rows by 600 columns.

For example, for the following "2x4" image:

```
>> A = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8]

A =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
     7     8

>> size(A)
ans =

     4     2
```

Comment: Thank you .In other words if i need  pixel (3,4,1)value in image i should write (4,3,1)?